# why the -1 in basis column for simplex tableau?

Tags: gurobi, simplex, cuts

When I look at the tableau generated by Gurobi for a simple 3D problem with five constraints, I get this:
[image]

I expected to not have a -1 in basis columns 4, 5, 6 (referring to slack variables 1, 2, 3 if you 0-index). I intend to use this for some intersection cut experiments. I'm obviously going to need to account for the -1 with those. How should I use that information (for intersection cuts)? Should I negate those rows? Should I negate my constraints that go with those slack variables when I use them to represent a slack variable in the cut? Or just the RHS or LHS of those constraints?

Comment: Does the problem have an optimal solution? Also, is it possible to write the basis variables via the `VBasis` method and check again what's happened?

Comment: @A.Omidi, this table came from an optimal solution point. The VBasis and CBasis both return -1 if not in the basis, so a negative number there doesn't relate.

Comment: In looking at VBasis, it has other information about the primary variables (being at upper/lower bound). However, the same information is not available via CBasis for the slack variables. The -1 in the table must expose that information somehow.

Comment: Is it possible to share your math model?

Comment: @A.Omidi, it's the example 6.3 from Conforti's book. It's here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9618/help-me-reproduce-this-tableau-from-the-integer-programming-book . Convert all constraints to $\geq$ and use continuous variables.

Comment: When I solved the problem with your mentioned modification, the model is an unbounded ray. (Actually it has an unbounded space). Do you check the model statues after the optimization terminates?

Comment: @A.Omidi, when converting the constraints you have to negate the terms. The original problem is not unbounded; negating constraints shouldn't change the boundedness of the problem.

Comment: @Branoon, I am not sure to understand what you mean by `negating constraints`. The original model contains five constraints. The first, forth, and fifth have the form of $\leq$ and the second and third have the form of $\geq$. As you said in the previous comment `Convert all constraints to ≥`, it is a bit confusing what you actually do with the modified model. By `negating` do you mean is the first, forth, and fifth should have the form of $\geq$ and the second and third should have the form of $\leq$? Otherwise, you totally solved a different model.

Comment: Also, if you mean by `negating constraints` is by converting only the $\leq$ constraints, yes, the results are the same as the original model and the basic variables already are the same as the original one. This is what I can get by the modified model: [x1, x2, x3] are basis.

Comment: However, I cannot see what you take as a basic variables with the reduced cost of -1. Is it possible to share your code?

Comment: @A.Omidi, I realized that I have the variables set to be binary, not integer. Hence, the problem is not quite identical to the example. I get the tableau from Gurobi's GRBBinvRowi function. I'm not going to share the code.

Comment: It is a bit hard to investigate whats happened without knowing the whole problem. Is it possible to share an LP file?